# bundle.js not found. React, Node, Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have generated bundle.js file but it is not available when I run server.
Same thing is for style.css.
Probably error is small but I can't find it.

build

```
NODE_ENV='production' webpack -p
```

start

```
NODE_ENV=production NODE_PATH=./src node  server.js
```

server.js

```
require('babel-core/register');
['.css', '.less', '.sass', '.ttf', '.woff', '.woff2'].forEach((ext) => require.extensions[ext] = () => {});
require('babel-polyfill');
require('server.js');
```

webpack.config.js

```
global.Promise         = require('bluebird');

const webpack            = require('webpack');
const path               = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin  = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const publicPath         = './public';
const cssName            = 'styles.css';
const jsName             = 'bundle.js';

const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      BROWSER:  JSON.stringify(true),
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin(cssName)
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  plugins.push(
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([ './public/' ], {
      root: __dirname,
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    })
  );
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin());
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client.js'],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  resolve: {
    root:               path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules' ],
    extensions:         ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins,
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/public/`,
    filename: jsName,
    publicPath
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader')
      },
      { test: /\.gif$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif' },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg' },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png' },
      { test: /\.svg/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=26000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=1' },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'react-hot!babel!eslint-loader' : 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: '.eslintrc'
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'source-map' : null,
  devServer: {
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  }
};
```

src/server.js

```
...
const assetUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'http://localhost:8050' : '';
function renderHTML(componentHTML, initialState) {
  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Hello React</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="${assetUrl}/public/styles.css">
          <script type="application/javascript">
            window.REDUX_INITIAL_STATE = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)};
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="react-view">${componentHTML}</div>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="${assetUrl}/public/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
}
...
```

any guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file you have given the `src` of the css and bundle.js file to start with `http://localhost:8050`, but src is always given with relative to the file you are in

you should use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles.css">
```

and

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="../public/bundle.js"></script>
```

The path comes from the assumption that `public` directory is directly outside the `src` directory.

Comment: I had to add some magic that was related on project structure. But your advice helped. Thanks a lot)